# Trying to get count and group by two columns at the same time

Tags: sql

My `df` has over 32k variables and looks like this:

[image: repeated los values for d32]

I want to get is something like this:

[image: for each <code>los</code>, count each <code>d32</code> that appears]

How do I get that count column?

I've been trying to use code below

```
create table result_table as 
  select los, d32, count(d32) as count
  from gosp
  group by los, d32;
```

but for some reasons I got this:

[image]

I don't know why it does something with the `los` column.

Comment: Why are you using a number as a table name?  That is quite awkward.

Comment: Column was in foreign language just changed that for forum post purposes.

Comment: Can you show the output of `select los, count(d32) from gosp group by los` ?

Comment: It got those weird numbers too:los _TEMG001
. 36
1,00 5222
1,06 1
1,26 1
1,50 1
1,56 3
1,61 2
1,67 1
1,70 1
1,90 1

Comment: It seems Ios contains decimal values. Your query seems correct, maybe you should examine your data before creating the query.